# Max querystring length on asp .net 2.0

Tags: query-string

I am working on ASP .NET version 2.0 and IIS 6. I am calling a pop up aspx page from the main page by calling its URL and passing querystring to it.
For a specific case the length of my querystring exceeds more than 2000 characters. So the pop up screen opens up fine for the first time but whenever there is a postback in that pop up screen, I get a internet connection error.
I am sure this is happening because of the large length of the querystring because it works fine when I reduce the length of querystring.

Is there a way we can increase the maximum allowed length of the querystring passed. Can it be configured through web.config or in some IIS settings.

Comment: if possible instead of sending such a long string in url, try using the FORM's POST method.

Answer (score 5):

Following is the approach I use for ASP.Net MVC 4

```
<system.web>

    <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="6000" />

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>

        <security>

            <requestFiltering>
                <!--Query String Length-->
                <requestLimits maxQueryString="6000" />
            </requestFiltering>         
        </security>

  </system.webServer>
```

REFERENCE

1. [request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength when using [Authorize]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159321/request-exceeds-the-configured-maxquerystringlength-when-using-authorize)
2. [WCF says it exceeds maximum query string value while it is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329385/wcf-says-it-exceeds-maximum-query-string-value-while-it-is-not)

Answer (score 4):

By default it 2048.  Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxquerystringlength.aspx) post (MSDN). Set `maxQueryStringLength` in `httpRuntime` section of your web.config.

Please check the requirements for this on the same post.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 3):

Attribute `maxQueryStringLength` of `httpRuntime` element is supported only by 4.0 and above.
You have to use IIS settings to control max query string limits.

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits