# How to increase size limit for HTTP header value in request for Azure IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, azure, iis

Token is passed in Authorization header in GET request like this:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token here>
```

Using trial and error I figured out that header value limit must be around **2048**, because requests with tokens smaller than that are passed to my ASP.NET app without any changes and requests with larger tokens have Authorization header removed triggering 401 in my app.

App is published to Azure. It doesn't seem to matter whether request is GET or POST.

Limit looks similar to [querystring limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922952/max-querystring-length-on-asp-net-2-0) so I've increased the allowed query string and it didn't help.

IIS version: 8.0 (from response headers)

Comment: Haven't tried - see if [this works](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/headerlimits) - see the sample `web.config` section. Hth.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the header length limit is 65536, which is set in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters` registry.  I tested it both on my local machine and Azure Web App. Here is the code I used to test with:

On server side I used

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content(Request.Headers["Authorization"]);
    }
}
```

On client side, I used

```cs
static async void SendRequest()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string token = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 2050; i++)
    {
        token = token + "0";
    }
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync("http://xxx.azurewebsites.net/");
    string content = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(content);
}
```

I can get the Authorization parameter back.

[image: Console prompt with extremely long Bearer value]

> Using trial and error I figured out that header value limit must be around 2048

Another place you might have a limit is the `headerLimits` config section.  You can add length limits for specific headers in this config section.

If I add this configuration to *web.config*…

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits>
        <headerLimits >
          <add header="Authorization" sizeLimit="2048" />
        </headerLimits>
      </requestLimits>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

…the request from my client was blocked and I got the following error:

[image: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.]

If I increase the `sizeLimit` to meet the length of request `Authorization` header, for example 2058. The request will be executed OK.

So please check whether you have modified the `headerLimits` config section in your *web.config* file. If yes, it will block your request if the length of this header is larger than the limit value. To solve it, we can increase the value of `sizeLimit` to modify the limit of Authorization header.

Comment: Hi @Amor- Is there any Azure documentation which confirm the below point
"By default, the header length limit is 65536" ? Thanks in advance.