# The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to redirect to a view and keep getting the error posted in the question title.

During breakpoint testing the code passing though the first bit of code iv lay down below setting the message and setting the exception. after continuing after the return redirect the very next page displayed is as follows.

[image]

Adding break points to the ErrorController and error model i found that the code never gets there.

The view i'm trying to post to is an error page. Here is so code to help you see the problem.

The RedirectToAction:

```
string message;
message = "An error has occured during the communication to lightstone, this is likely a timeout issue and could be the result of a bad connection. Please go back and try again.";
return RedirectToAction("Error", "Error", new { ex = ex.ToString(), message =  message});
```

The action in my ErrorController:

```
public ActionResult Error(string ex, string message)
{
   ViewBag.Message = "Error";
   return View(new ErrorModel(ex, message));
}
```

My Error model:

```
namespace MvcResComm.Models
{
    public class ErrorModel
    {
        public string ex { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }

        public ErrorModel(string ex, string message)
        {
            this.ex = ex;
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159321/request-exceeds-the-configured-maxquerystringlength-when-using-authorize for an answer.

Comment: I understand the problem now, but still have no working solution to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use `TempData`, it's meant to do stuff like this. So for example:

```
TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "An error has occured during the communication to lightstone, this is likely a timeout issue and could be the result of a bad connection. Please go back and try again.";
```

Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

**EDIT**

Pass your exception message like this:

```
TempData["Error"] = ex.Message();
TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "An error has occured during the communication to lightstone, this is likely a timeout issue and could be the result of a bad connection. Please go back and try again.";

return RedirectToAction("Error", "Error");
```

Then just access it from your `ErrorController`, something like:

```
public ActionResult Error(string ex, string message)
{
    var error = (string)TempData["Error"];
    // do other magic ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will make sure to do this, but i think the error is before i get tho the error controller. The error happens from the redirect to action.

Comment: @Pomster sorry I wasn't clear, check my edit. I hope it helps.

Comment: @Pomster, Actually, I didn't test it, but I'm pretty sure you can pass it straight to the view (I mean you can access `TempData["Error"]` directly in your view, you don't have to pass it).

Comment: Great thanks it works, In the action result just remove the (string ex, string message), in the parameter section and left the code the same useing the TempDate[] to pass the large strings. Thanks alot huge help, Following the other answers i would have a huge url on my error pages, this is defiantly the better way.

Answer (score 25):

In the root `web.config` for your project, under the `system.web` node:

```xml
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="10999" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />
...
```

In addition, I had to add this under the `system.webServer` node or I got a security error for my long query strings:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="9999" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
...
```

Comment: My `system.webserver` contains already `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0"/>` so I've updated it to `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" maxUrlLength="10999" maxQueryStringLength="2097151"  />`. In case I've added a new `httpRuntime` tag, I've got an `IIS 500.19` error.

Answer (score 2):

In you web.config 
under the `<system.web> <httpRuntime>` tags you can set your `maxQueryStringLength`

so its like

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength = "**MY NUMBER**" />
</system.web>
```

check out the msdn reference :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Also please increase maxQueryStringLength  in the IIS configuration, check out :

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits

Comment: Iv set this to large numbers and nothing has happened?

Comment: <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" maxUrlLength="1000000" maxQueryStringLength="1000000"/>

Comment: check out my edit. there is also a way to increase the maxQueryStringLength from IIS

Answer (score 1):

There is a maxumum URL length value settable in the web.config file. This question has a similar problem
[ASP.NET MVC, Url Routing: Maximum Path (URL) Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185739/asp-net-mvc-url-routing-maximum-path-url-length)

Comment: The error happens from the redirect to action? why would Url length have a effect?

Comment: Because the URL length is a defined limit on the size of the GET request. This is done to ensure support for earlier browsers that could not handle URL lengths over a certain size. When you redirect to an Action (on the controller) it does a GET on that action

Comment: Thanks ok i see now, how would i then pass these strings from the one controller where the error occurs to the Error Controller, with out having to pass it in the url?

Or how do i set max url size?

<httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" maxUrlLength="1000000" maxQueryStringLength="1000000"/>

Answer (score 0):

I fixed follow:
It run Ok

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <alwaysAllowedQueryStrings>
                <add queryString="maxQueryString" />
                <add queryString="maxAllowedContentLength" />
                <add queryString="maxUrl" />
            </alwaysAllowedQueryStrings>
            <requestLimits maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="2097151" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

And add

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="10999" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />
</system.web>
```

[image: web.config]

Answer (score 0):

this fixed my problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="10999" maxQueryStringLength="2097151"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="9999"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>         
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```