# Asp.Net Sending large amounts of data from view to controller

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a Asp.net MVC application. In my project, I'm using a third party JavaScript library called [Dhtmlx Scheduler](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/).

There is a function in this library then writes all the data on the scheduler into XML format.
I then need to manipulate this data, and write in back onto a `<textarea>` on my view page.

as of now this is what I have:

View:

```
function save() {
    var url = "/Home/Save"

    var xml = scheduler.toXML();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        Type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: { xmlString: xml },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: alert("File Saved in C:\\ Drive as Tasks.xml")
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Save(string xmlString)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    try
    {
        doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
    doc.Save(@"C:\\Tasks.xml");

    W6ViewModel viewModel = new W6ViewModel();
    viewModel.engineers = db.W6ENGINEERS.ToList();
    viewModel.tasks = db.W6TASKS.ToList();
    viewModel.skills = db.W6TASKS_REQUIRED_SKILLS1.ToList();
    viewModel.categories = db.W6TASKTYPECATEGORY.ToList();

    gatherInfo(viewModel);

    return View("Index", viewModel);
}
```

When trying to save three events (Dhtmlx objects) it works flawlessly, when trying to add more data to the XML I get this error (read form FireBug):

> The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured
>   maxQueryStringLength value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Firebug Console:
[image]

Comment: Are you using FireBug to simulate the POST?

Comment: have you looked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159321/request-exceeds-the-configured-maxquerystringlength-when-using-authorize)

Comment: In firebug - is json sent in body request? If yes, you should try to get content of body directly from request `Stream`, not via binder.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not to experienced with the terminology or FireBug for that matter. But yes, the content is located in the body section of the page.

Comment: What @pwas and I are essentially asking is: how is the data being sent to your controller? Your error suggests it is being sent as a query string instead of HTTP POST body content.

Comment: In a network tab, you should be able to see the `POST` request that you are sending. Check if json object is stored in URL or after the request headers.

Comment: I believe the info is being posted in the URL, check my edit picture for reference. I hope this is what you guys meant.

Comment: That's the problem - you are making `GET` instead of `POST`. First of all, change `Type` to `type` in `$.ajax`. Secondly, add `HttpPost` attribute to your action. Without this, action will work only for `GET` requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe jQuery.ajax uses `type` and not `Type`. This is case sensitive. If you look at your Firebug it is doing a GET request instead of a POST:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    Type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: { xmlString: xml },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: alert("File Saved in C:\\ Drive as Tasks.xml")
});
```

should be

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: { xmlString: xml },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: alert("File Saved in C:\\ Drive as Tasks.xml")
});
```

Comment: Very important: controller's action should be decorated with `HttpPost` attribute - otherwise will be visible only for `GET` requests.

Comment: @pwas If you don't decorate a controller, it can be either POST or GET (probably event DELETE, PUT, etc). If he had decorated it with `HttpPost` however, he would have gotten a 404 and the problem might have been easier to identify.

Comment: @Dismissile:I think default value is HttpGET

Comment: @malkam I just wrote a quick demo program to prove this and if you do not use any attribute on an action method in MVC, then it will accept GET or POST.

Comment: Hello, after making the apporpiate changes mentioned above, I now get this error:

Invalid JSON primitive: xmlString.

Comment: @malkam There isn't really a default as such, but adding the attribute will restrict it to that method only.

Answer (score 1):

Grr I can't comment yet, I seem to recall if you pass one primitive value you do

```
data: xml
```

rather than

```
data : { xmlString: xml }
```

Comment: unfortunately, this did not solve my problem, I had it like that before so the xml will map to the Action variable.

Comment: Now the controller is decorated with [HttpPost] use public ActionResult Save([FromBody] string xmlString)

Comment: using the [FromBody] but use data: { "" : xml } its in there somewhere! racking my brains as I had this problem a while back

Comment: I appreciate the help!
but i tried both the original and your suggestion of { "" : xml } 

still no results.

Comment: data = "{'xmlString':'" + xml + "' }" if thats no help then its time for tea and I shall get my hat and coat.

Comment: Ir worked!!!!

wish i could put your suggestion as an answer, but its not answer the question posted originally!
A big thanks!

Answer (score -1):

has explained in this post -> [request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength when using [Authorize]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159321/request-exceeds-the-configured-maxquerystringlength-when-using-authorize)

you should change the configuration setting in your web.config to allow more that the 2048 character of the default value.

so basicly you need to change the 
`<httpRuntime maxRequestLength = "" maxQueryStringLength ="">`
to the number you find acceptable.

Edit: have you tried to change your `Type: "POST"` to `type: "POST"` ?
since javascript is a case sensitive language.

As for the invalid Json primitive try this :

```
    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            data: 'xmlString='+ xml,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: alert("File Saved in C:\\ Drive as Tasks.xml")
        });
```

Comment: This is probably a very bad idea. the code should be putting the data in the POST body, not in a query string.

Comment: This does solve the problem, but I fear it is not the best way to go about sending large information to the server.

Is there another way of sending data?

Comment: that is true, while the method i posted should get you running there is mostly a problem in the code elsewhere that take the post data and convert it to query string.

Comment: Yes, exactly, as of now, I don't know of a better way of handling this situation.

Comment: can we se your route configuration ? please