# Issue with Query String Parameter Length. Http Error 400

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, webserver, windows-server-2008

Can anyone please tell me issue with my URL:-
http://www.advantarealty.net/Search//Condo,Single-Family-Home,Townhome_PropertyType/True_ForMap/8_Zoom/-81.3043212890625T29.099376992628493,-80.88134765625T28.9120147012556,-80.826416015625T28.41555985166584,-81.1669921875T28.033197847676377,-81.6888427734375T28.033197847676377,-82.1392822265625T28.222130007158537,-82.2601318359375T28.584521719370418,-82.1612548828125T28.92163128242129,-81.9305419921875T29.257648503615542,-81.6339111328125T29.248063243796576,-81.6064453125T28.849485201023,-81.3043212890625T29.099376992628493_Polygon/

I'm getting below error always.

**Bad Request - Invalid URL.
HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.**

In above URL, I guess it's exceeding maximum query string parameter length so i tried increasing it like below.

```
<system.web>
    <!--<httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536"/>-->
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxUrlLength="2097151" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxUrl="40960" maxQueryString="2097151" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

I have tried 
[request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength when using [Authorize]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159321/request-exceeds-the-configured-maxquerystringlength-when-using-authorize)

[How to configure the web.config to allow requests of any length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636386/how-to-configure-the-web-config-to-allow-requests-of-any-length)

Comment: Have you tried in non ie browsers, they offers upto 5 mb of data

Comment: I'm checking in Chrome 43, FF 39

Comment: @JitendraPancholi Hello sir, are you get the solution, then please help me for the same.

Comment: @Abhishek: Yes, I will add the solution asap.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi How did you solved this?

Comment: Hi @JitendraPancholi can u share the solution please

Answer (score 0):

You have forward slashes in your URL that don't seem to belong.  If you replace

"http://www.advantarealty.net/Search//Condo,Single-Family-Home,Townhome_PropertyType/True_ForMap/8_Zoom/..."

with

"http://www.advantarealty.net/Search/Condo,Single-Family-Home,Townhome_PropertyType,True_ForMap,8_Zoom,"

you will have a valid URL.  I proved this by copying the URL from your question and replacing those extraneous "/"s.

Comment: that's not an issue, I have added proper routing to accept any data in query string. And my problem has been resolved now. But thanks for the reply.

Comment: Interesting...the link in your original question didn't render anything on Firefox (38) unless I replaced the slashes with commas.  Anyway, glad you got it working.