# How to configure maxQueryStringLength in webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I wrote a method in webapi that get data by json format. This work currently but when I call this method by another parameters that length of query  string is 2154 character get me error that :

> The length of the query string for this request exceeds the
> configured maxQueryStringLength value.
>
> Description: An unhandled
> exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
> Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
> where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The length of the query
> string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength
> value.

I add to webconfig below code inside `system.webServer` section

```
<security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="5000" maxUrl="5000" maxAllowedContentLength="102400000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

but don't solved.

webapi method :

```
 [HttpPost,HttpGet]
    
    public IHttpActionResult LockSeats(string ticketsJson, bool checkCompartment, string userId, string ipAddress)
    {
        try
        {
            List<WagonAvaliableResponse> tickets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WagonAvaliableResponse>>(ticketsJson);
            AdakTrainLibrary.ResultLockSeat resultLockSeat = _adakTrain.LockSeats(tickets, 1, 1, "1", "1", checkCompartment, userId, ipAddress, TrainUserId, TrainPass);
            return Ok(resultLockSeat);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Ok(e);
        }
    }
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159321/request-exceeds-the-configured-maxquerystringlength-when-using-authorize help?

Comment: ok it solved...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I add this code into `system.webServer` section

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxUrl="30000" maxQueryString="209007151" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

and  add

```
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="10240" maxQueryStringLength="2097100"  targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
```

into `system.web` section and solved

Comment: This webapi added to the web application project. This API worked inside website.